# Unity AndroidJavaObject java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I want to get userAgent on Unity.
platform is Android.

But NoSuchMethodError 
why??
Im not good at english. sorry

```
    AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject context = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity").Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

    AndroidJavaObject webView = new AndroidJavaObject ("android/webkit/WebView", context);
    AndroidJavaObject webViewSetting = webView.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getSettings");
    string userAgent = webViewSetting.Call<string>("getUserAgentString");
```

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: hi.
error is this line.
AndroidJavaObject webView = new AndroidJavaObject ("android/webkit/WebView", context);

Comment: is "android/webkit/WebView" class name?

Comment: yes.
this class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: see this link if it helps http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/passing-androidjavaobject-as-call-parameter.218311/

Comment: thank you. I watch this page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "." and not "/" in the class name

**Correct**

```
 AndroidJavaObject webView = new AndroidJavaObject ("android.webkit.WebView", context);
```